# Which C++ cross platform GUI framework has good skinning ability?

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform, themes, skins

What is a cross-platform C++ GUI framework that has good skinning ability?

So I could (and give the users) the ability to customise the GUI.

Comment: when you think "skinning", do you also want non native titlebars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: As you're looking for something like [wxSkin](http://www.upcase.de/wxSkin.html), first why not use it in the first place?

Then, if you don't want to use wxSkin, have a look at Juce. Qt's goal is definitely not themeable GUIs although windows masks and stylesheets are a way to implement them. There is the [QSkingObject project on Qt-Apps.org](http://www.qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QSkinObject?content=67309) but last time I checked it I found that the quality of the code was poor (of course this is subjective and argumentative).

---

You can have a look at [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce/) which has a dual license: GPL and commercial.

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) (LGPL) has stylesheets to style the widgets, but it still let the operating system draw the windows decorations unless you instruct it to draw frameless windows and draw the decorations by yourself.

However, think twice before going the skinned application route. A typical example is [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) (written in XUL) which used frameless windows and painted its own titlebar and windows buttons. Then they back-pedaled and switch back to system windows decorations after many users complained.

Comment: dono its seams experimental , i dont know if it will be good in production

Comment: well, at least Juce has been used in music softwares and in fact it has been developed when writing tracktion

Answer (score 11):

The Qt framework allows for changing the appearance of widgets using style sheets (using css). See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html.

Answer (score 3):

Qt has convenient support for that with [Qt style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html) et al. The Qt labs blog had an [example post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2007/11/27/theming-qt-for-fun-and-profit/) that might give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

As other say, Qt's stylesheets work well.

You also have the option to customize the drawing in Qt by overriding QStyle. You could allow users to use plugins (exporting a QStyle implementation) to make it super-customizable.

(Then, I don't know if your users are C++ coders or not...)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) (compatible with Windows, Linux and Mac OS X) in the past and it has a [LookAndFeel](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/api/classLookAndFeel.html) class (gotta love the name) that allows you to do that.

Comment: Java also call its UI customization LookAndFeel, so there's precedent on that name (however wonky it might be ;).

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to vote for [XULRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XULRunner) because it's *extremely* skinnable. However, it's not pure C++: application code is written in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) while extensions can be implemented as C++ [XPCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM) components.